# Maximum distance of two tree nodes with same color

Tags: algorithm, tree, shortest-path, graph-coloring, lowest-common-ancestor

Given a tree with `N` vertices where each edge has weight `1`. The nodes are colored with `C` colors. We wish to find, for each color, the maximum shortest distance between two nodes of that color.

I can build a sparse table and then find LCA of two nodes in `O(log n)`. Then check all pairs of same color. This gives `O(n^2 log n)`. Is it possible to do better than this?

Answer (score 0):

You can juggle the edges properly and run a recursive traversal starting form each node as if it is the root. As the tree has N nodes, N traversals would give you **O(N<sup>2</sup>)**. The *juggling* of the edges should take **O(n)** time as well, as there are (n-1) edges in a tree. If you keep a matrix M with C rows and C columns and update it as go through each traversal, then you can do what you desire in **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** overall time *and* space complexity.

Basically what you do will be updating the c<sub>u</sub><sup>th</sup> row of M in a traversal starting from node U with color c<sub>u</sub> in the following manner when you reach node V with color c<sub>v</sub> at distance d.

```
M[cu][cv] = max(M[cu][cv], d)
```